# Installation Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS not working

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, everything seemed to go well. 
At the end it tells me to restart to finish the installation with a button 'restart now'. 
When i press that button everything gets stuck, so i forced the laptop to go off. 
After re-boot, all i see is the Ubuntu background with 'Ubuntu 16.04 LTS' in the left corner and i am able to see a white mouse which i can move, that's all.

Did re-installations like 100 time and problem still exist...

I downloaded the ISO file from the official website s://www.ubuntu.com/download
then i used Rufus to make my USB bootable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't say what device you installed from. But I can tell you that if you have a faulty UFD left in a machine on Shutdown or Restart the machine often hangs as it tries to shut the device down. The same thing can happen on boot-up - GRUB menu never reached. Not saying that's your issue but if you left the installing device in the computer, remove it.

Comment: I tried installing Ubuntu on my laptop: Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G=52FG.
Yes, i removed the USB before i rebooted the laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually very hard for me to tell, what could be wrong. I suppose you have one display. Then I suppose, you almost booted ubuntu, and you are not able to login and your mouse is not working. Then try what @eduardo-ortega102 may have suggested.

On ubuntu screen press:
 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

if you are able to get to a command line (black screen with text). Then try to login (name and then password). If this is possible it is good sign, I suppose. If not, than I am not able to help.

Comment: Well when i boot up, it actually asks me for my password, after that i have to enter my password again to actually login, and after then it gets stuck on a page i described in my post.

Comment: As I see it, you have problem with GUI. So try if it is possible to boot through ctrl-alt-F1. If it does not make error. You can try install midnight commander if you are not friendly with command line commands.
First try it run:
`$ mc`
If it does not start, try:
`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa`
`$ sudo apt-get update`
`$ sudo apt-get install mc`
I suppose, that if there is problem with GUI, you probably have to solve it through command line. But I am not so experienced. Anyway if you can simply login and logout in command line it is good sign.

Comment: I tried with ctrl-alt-F1, it completely crashed and nothing responds.

Comment: Then it looks like it is much worse than I expected in my last post. I wish you someone with more experience would help you. Do you have other system on your laptop to boot?